# Extract Notification Pending Intent Content for Accessibility

Tags: android, android-intent, accessibility, android-pendingintent

I'm working on accessibility features for my Android application, one of which is to announce to the user their notifications.

Using the following standard code, I can access notification information:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {

        final Notification not = (Notification) event.getParcelableData();
        final CharSequence tick = not.tickerText;
        final PendingIntent pi = not.contentIntent;
```

But here I'm stuck at how I can extract information from the PendingIntent to establish, for example, which Activity (if any) it points at.

I can establish the originator, using further standard code of:

```
final String packageName = event.getPackageName().toString()
```

This is fine in most cases, but many notifications are from Google Services Framework or Android System and therefore the [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) information would give further clues as to what exactly they are - A good example of this would be GTalk, which is under the generic Package Name of Google Services Framework.

I've read many [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004006/how-can-i-get-the-intent-extras-for-a-pendingintent-that-is-already-pending?rq=1), including how to [action the Pending Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653138/get-intent-from-notification-via-accessbility-service-android), but I can't work out how to just access this information, or if it is possible.

```
pi.getCreatorPackage();
pi.getTargetPackage();
```

Both return Google Services Framework (in the case of GTalk)

```
pi.readPendingIntentOrNullFromParcel(?);
```

Looks a little more promising, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

I hope you can help, or tell me it's not possible! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. The contents of the `PendingIntent` are managed by the `ActivityManager` and there is no API available to get this data from the `ActivityManager`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does appear you're correct, as I can find nothing. I'll give it a few more days in hope and then mark you answer as correct. Is there anything I can get from Reflection do you know?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've tried this. I dug through the source code for `PendingIntent`, `ActivityManager` and `ActivityManagerNative` and it looks like there are no methods (even private methods) or fields that contain the actual data associated with the `Intent`. This data is all kept within the `ActivityManagerService` and there don't seem to be any callable methods to access this data. Sorry.

Comment: This is a shame.  PendingIntent provides a great way to safely hold some state in memory for an app (as it will survive the app being killed) but altering that state is problematic in some cases.